# How to get esbuild to export a default module vs IIFE's

Tags: javascript, typescript, esbuild

I want it to export this ts entry

with a export default (so I can dynamically import it in browser) not as shown below:

[image]

I ran esbuild like so:

`"esbuild": "esbuild src/i18n/en.ts --bundle --outfile=dist/i18n/en.js",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the format of the output, esbuild has the flag [`--format`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format).

To emit esm you can use [`--format=esm`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format-esm).

For the options you used, [`--format=iife`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format-iife) is the default. When each format is chosen as the default can be seen in the [`--format` documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format).